# How can I make a shape like this using css and div

Tags: css

https://www.cp24.com/polopoly_fs/7.687199!/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/default/image.jpg

I want to accomplish something similar to the image attached, I tried several post but didn't get it done, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: For future reference and to avoid your question being down-voted or closed, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We aren't here to write code for you, we're here to help you debug your existing code.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilise the CSS `:after` pseudo-element to achieve a similar item, for example:

```css
#banner {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#banner > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#banner .banner-grey {
  background: #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

#banner .banner-grey:after {
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: #aaa;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: 0;
}

#banner .banner-red {
  background: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -4px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

#banner .banner-red span {
  color: #fff;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div class="banner-grey">Check out our <b>live and interactive screen</b></div>
  <div class="banner-red"><span>CP24</span>now</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you're genius!

Comment: @user1554459 No problem!